# Select statement that arranges criteria in their own columns

Tags: sql, select, sum, sas

This is probably easy stuff, but I've scoured the documentation and can't figure it out. Here's the source table:

```
store  item  date       sales
101   00001  27-Oct-12  1
101   00002  27-Oct-12  0
102   00001  27-Oct-12  2  
102   00002  27-Oct-12  1
101   00001  3-Nov-12   0 
101   00002  3-Nov-12   0
102   00001  3-Nov-12   1
102   00002  3-Nov-12   1
```

...and I'm trying to write a query to end up with a table of monthly sales with the stores having their own columns for, say, just item #00001--

```
monthyear  store101sales otherstoresales
10/2012    1             2
11/2012    0             1
```

Here's the code I've tried--

```
select distinct 
    year(date) as SalesYear,
    month(date) as SalesMonth,
    sum(case when store in (101) then sales.count else 0 end) as store101sales,
    sum(case when store in (102,103) then sales.count else 0 end) as otherstoresales,
from source_table
where item=00001;
GROUP BY SalesYear, SalesMonth, store101sales, otherstoresales,
ORDER BY SalesYear, SalesMonth, store101sales, otherstoresales;
```

Any help appreciated; thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, don't need to `GROUP BY` aggregates, and not sure if MySQL allows for using aliases in `GROUP BY` or not:

```
select year(date) as SalesYear,
    month(date) as SalesMonth,
    sum(case when store in (101) then sales else 0 end) as store101sales,
    sum(case when store in (102,103) then sales else 0 end) as otherstoresales
from source_table
where item=00001;
GROUP BY year(date), month(date)
ORDER BY SalesYear, SalesMonth, store101sales, otherstoresales;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this; it's still not working though. Here are the errors I get: ERROR: Unresolved reference to table/correlation name sales.
ERROR: Unresolved reference to table/correlation name sales.
ERROR: Result of WHEN clause 2 is not the same data type as the preceding results.
ERROR: The SUM summary function requires a numeric argument.
ERROR: Result of WHEN clause 2 is not the same data type as the preceding results.
ERROR: The SUM summary function requires a numeric argument.

Comment: Ah, wasn't paying attention,.  You had `sales.count` which would reference a field `count` in a table aliased as `sales`, so I believe the update above should do it.

Comment: Perfect! I had imagined that to refer to some count method of the sales object necessary for getting the sum. Thanks again for your time and helping to enhance my SQL literacy.

Comment: No problem, if you did want a count and not the sum of a field, you can use `SUM(CASE WHEN criteria THEN 1 END)` and it will act as a count for that case.